Groovy loop through Pattern matches
    def regex = 'crt1234[a-z]_(\\w\\w)_DTS(.*)'
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("crt1234_DH_DTS")
    matcher.findAll() 

How do I loop through the matches? When I try the following it throws an IllegalStateEx
    for(i in 1..<matcher.count)
    group += matcher.group(i)

I am able to concat the groups using the following code
matcher.findAll() { newGroup -> group += newGroup }

Couple issues; your Regex isn't actually matching anything in the example string, you would need to add a ? after the a-z range like so: crt1234[a-z]?_(\w\w)_DTS(.*). Then before the matcher.group() call you need to call the matcher.find() method. Once called your groups should be populated.

Thanks for your suggestion. I tried both - adding a ? in the regex and the call to matcher.find() in the loop - but the groups are still not being populated. What am I doing wrong?

Just added an answer with a complete answer. I tested the code and I seem to be getting the expected results. Let me know if you have any issues and I can attempt to help!

The call to the group method will always fail if there has been no attempt to match the input which is what you are experiencing. Before any calls to the group() method, you need to actually attempt to match. This can be done by calling the find() method on the matcher prior to calling the group() method.
Here is an example found on Geeks for Geeks (modified for your use case):
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

// Get the regex to be checked
String regex = "crt1234[a-z]?_(\\w\\w)_DTS(.*)";

// Create a pattern from regex
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

// Get the String to be matched
String stringToBeMatched = "crt1234_DH_DTS";

// Create a matcher for the input String
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToBeMatched);

//find match
matcher.find()

//get matched group at index 1 (0 will be full match, not group)
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //outputs: DH

After some more investigation, it seems calling the matcher.count property (groovy enhancement), the groups are cleared and matcher.find() does not result in any more groups. To work around this, you can call matcher.reset() after accessing the matcher.count, then calling matcher.find() works as expected and you can access the matched groups using matcher.group(). Here is an example:
String regex = "crt1234[a-z]?_(\\w\\w)_DTS(.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String stringToBeMatched = "crt1234_DH_DTS";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToBeMatched);

//get the count (this will break matcher.group() until matcher.reset() is called
Integer count = matcher.count

//reset the matcher and match the groups
matcher.reset()
matcher.find()

//get matched groups
for(Integer i=0;i<=count;i++){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}


Why don't the groups get populated when I use a FOR loop instead of the WHILE loop?

Not sure if you were able to get it working, but I've found that calling matcher.count seems to prevent the matcher.find() from getting the groups. If you call matcher.reset() after accessing matcher.count, you should be able to use the for loop as expected. Hope that helps, I'll update the answer with these findings.

@user3411153 I've updated the answer with a working forloop example, hope that helps!

Thanks for the updated answer. I was able to test it out locally without any issues but when I try it in my application it doesn't work. In my application, I have defined the regex pattern as a property and read it in as a string.

I'm guessing your issue is due to the escaping of the \w in the regex, but is is hard to say for sure. If you update the string to crt1234[a-z]?_(\\\\w\\\\w)_DTS(.*) or crt1234[a-z]?_(\w\w)_DTS(.*) does it work?


In Java (and by extension Groovy) Matcher iterates over matches of your pattern, not groups
Groups (AKA capturing groups) are those things you put in parenthesis: (\w\w) and (.*). You can iterate over them, sure, but the number of groups doesn't vary from string to string - it's always the ones you defined in your pattern. The number of matches can obviously vary
In Java (and by extension Groovy) Matcher follows a streaming-like approach - you can progress by calling .find(), but you can't go backwards. Methods like getCount() and size() consume the "stream" and you have to reset() to iterate over it again
You can make your life a little easier if you use Groovy as Groovy, not as C

// create a pattern with a `~` operator and use `slashy` strings
def pattern = ~/crt1234[a-z]?_(\w\w)_DTS(.*)/
// create a matcher with a `=~` operator
def matcher = 'crt1234_DH_DTS' =~ pattern
// iterate with an `Iterator`
matcher.each {
  println it[1] // `1` here refers to group 1
}


This answers the question way better than I did. This should probably be the accepted answer, not mine. Maybe @user3411153 can update this answer to the accepted if they see it.
